# Unable to identify Thread 1 in Swift 5: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift5

I'm building an IOS dictionary app. I am creating a viewTable with a searchBar to search for the words and display search results as being typed. For example, if user types in "app", the viewTable should display "app, apple, apply" etc. Heres what I have, please help, and thank you.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var wordSearch = [String]()
    var searching = false
    var wordArray: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "words_alpha", withExtension: "txt")! // file URL for file "words_alpha.txt"
               do {
                   let string = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
                   wordArray = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
               } catch {
                   print(error)
               }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return wordArray.count
        } else {
            return wordArray.count
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell");cell?.textLabel?.text = wordArray[indexPath.row]
        if searching {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = wordSearch[indexPath.row] //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
        } else {
            cell?.textLabel?.text = wordSearch[indexPath.row]
        }
            return cell!
        }
    }

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        wordSearch = wordArray.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText;})
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to handle the case if the search field is empty.

And there is a more efficient and reliable syntax to filter the array: `range(of` can filter case insensitive and from the beginning of the string (`anchored`) simultaneously.

```
extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            searching = false
            wordSearch.removeAll()
        } else {
            wordSearch = wordArray.filter{ $0.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil }
            searching = true
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

To fix the error you have to get the data from `wordSearch` or `wordArray` depending on `searching`. Replace `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searching ? wordSearch.count : wordArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for indexPath)
    let word = searching ? wordSearch[indexPath.row] : wordArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = word
    return cell
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was having difficulties with the capitalization, you're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You set a count of array

```
if searching {
  return wordArray.count
```

and index the other 1 here

```
if searching {
   cell?.textLabel?.text = wordSearch[indexPath.row] //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

So Use

```
if searching {
  return wordSearch.count
} else {
  return wordArray.count
}
```

along with

```
if searching {
     cell?.textLabel?.text = wordSearch[indexPath.row] //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
} else {
    cell?.textLabel?.text = wordArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no error, however, the tableView is empty when I start typing on the searchBar on the simulator. It seems the array is empty. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
The above answer is right . 

Adding to it. The search filtering g method seems to be wrong

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        **wordSearch = wordArray.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText;})**
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
   }

Instead use **wordArray.filter({$0.contains(searchText)})**

And on clearing the search bar . Reset searching = false and empty the wordSearch array.
Check whether you need to set the searchBar.delegate = self in viewDidLoad.
```